# How to customize subscribe() behaviour with a Sink in Project Reactor?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

For a `Flux` you can specify a custom action that happens upon subscription. For instance `Flux.create(emitter -> someApi.setCallback(emitter::next))` will set some API hooks upon subscription.

How can we have a custom subscription action like this for a sink? E.g. `Sinks.unsafe().many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer(someAction)`?

---

I've managed to make it work using `Flux.concat(Mono.fromRunnable(someAction), sink)` but I imagine that adds unnecessary overhead so not ideal.

Comment: There is a `doOnSubscribe` operator. Does that fit your purpose? `sink.asFlux().doOnSubscribe(...)`

Comment: @MartinTarjányi thats exactly what I was looking for thanks -- if you post as an answer I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`doOnSubscribe`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#doOnSubscribe-java.util.function.Consumer-) operator:

```java
sink.asFlux().doOnSubscribe(someAction)
```